# camel getRouteDefinitions not finding route

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel

In a unit test, I try to get a route definition to mock some endpoint. But the route is not found.  My unit test code is

```
@Autowired
CamelContext context;
List<RouteDefinition> defs = context.getRouteDefinitions();
```

The service is running fine, in particular the problematic routes are found and used. The unit test uses the same configuration as the production code. Nevertheless, although `defs` holds many of my routes, all defined in a particular bean are missing. This bean is loaded in the same configuration (also used in production) as the beans that hold the other routes and I cannot see any difference between them.

Creating a minimal example seems to be difficult because the service is quite complex. So, first I'd like to ask if there are any known issues with `getRouteDefinitions()`.

Comment: Could you please add more code, e.g. the class definition of your test class as well as your mentioned configuration.

Answer (score 0):

context.getRouteDefinitions() depricate and removed.

Old usage -

context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder(){})

Replace with -

context.addRoutes( new AdviceWithRouteBuilder(){})

Migration Guide - https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html

Comment: While this question may seem to answer the question at hand, keep in mind that this question was asked almost 5 years ago when there was no Camel 3. The actual problem the OP had was probably caused by something different that he did not include in the actual question, like a wrong test setup or something similar